# AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent without asking to create account

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account, android-account

I want the user to choose an existing account from my Android App. I'm using

```
Intent googlePicker = AccountManager
        .newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE},
                true, null, null, null, null);
a.startActivityForResult(googlePicker, ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

but I cannot find in the documentation the way to avoid requesting to create a new account. Is it possible to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Is there an option you can pass to avoid the add account option?

Answer (score 0):

You need google sign in for that:

First of all visit below link:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Then follow this tutorial:

https://androidclarified.com/google-signin-android-example/